# How to remove default padding in Text Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the android view, we can add the TextView data by:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

What is the replacement for **includeFontPadding** in compose ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
style = TextStyle(
    platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
        includeFontPadding = false,
    ),
),
```

And Opt-in using `@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)`.

Note: `PlatformTextStyle` is deprecated with the following message.

> Enables turning on and off for Android includeFontPadding .
>
> includeFontPadding was added to Android in order to prevent clipping
> issues on tall scripts. However that issue has been fixed since
> Android 28. Jetpack Compose backports the fix for Android versions
> prior to Android 28. Therefore the original reason why
> includeFontPadding was needed in invalid on Compose.
> This configuration was added for migration of the apps in case some
> code or design was relying includeFontPadding=true behavior and will be removed.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171394808

Compose version: `"1.2.0-beta02"`

Sample code and screenshot

[image: Sample]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun TextWithoutPadding() {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = AnnotatedString("Sample Text"),
            fontSize = 64.sp,
            style = TextStyle(
                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                    includeFontPadding = true,
                ),
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = Cyan,
                ),
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(
            text = AnnotatedString("Sample Text"),
            fontSize = 64.sp,
            style = TextStyle(
                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                    includeFontPadding = false,
                ),
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = Cyan,
                ),
        )
    }
}
```

Refer to this article for a details explanation of this topic.
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b

Comment: Wow, thanks, so far I'm still using the stable version of compose.

Thank you very much.