# How to remove font top padding in text jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to remove top padding in jetpack compose. I am using `compose_bom = "2023.03.00"`. I tried to use `includeFontPadding` to `false`. But still not working.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ShowText() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello!! How are you?",
            style = Typography(
                body1 = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp),
            ).body1.copy(
                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                    includeFontPadding = false,
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

If you see in above image. It's clearly have top padding in words.

Comment: Refer https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b

Answer (score 2):

The code is working, the space you see is not font padding.

You can increase the font size and toggle the flag to see the difference.

References,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72445755/9636037
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b

---

---

Difference between enabled and disabled font padding.

[image][image]

```
@Composable
fun FontPadding() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello!! How are you?",
            style = Typography(
                body1 = TextStyle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontSize = 72.sp,
                ),
            ).body1.copy(
                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                    includeFontPadding = false,
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

---

---

I have shared the article link as it has more details. The font glyph would have some default padding, which differs from the `fontPadding` applied by Android.

You can observe the same in this image from the blog.

[image]

Comment: If that is not font padding then how it coming the space ?

Comment: Updated the answer. I have shared the article link as it has more details. The font glyph would have some default padding, which differs from the `fontPadding` applied by Android.